# Visualiser for spatial query results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, spatial

This question [Whats the easiest way to get sql 08 spatial data onto a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382769/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-sql-08-spatial-data-onto-a-map) (and many other articles) recommends Craig Dunn's Geoquery, but all the download links appear to be kaput.

SQL Server Managament Studio's spatial results tab will show a single dataset, and this MSDN article, [Spatial Data Support In SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434647.aspx#id0080059) mentions a workaround using `UNION ALL` to display point data overlayed on a map:

```
SELECT geog, name FROM Mondial.dbo.city WHERE geog IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL 
SELECT geog, cntry_name FROM SpatialSamples.dbo.cntry00
```

Whenever I try something similar, I only ever get a single resultset displayed.

Is there something built into either SQL Server 2008 or 2012 to do this?

Comment: Have you found anything that will integrate with SSMS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Excel 2013 - it has fairly easy Map integration which can take Lat+Lon, eg:

http://www.sqljason.com/2013/03/geospatial-analytics-microsoft-bi-john.html

I would pull a SQL view through PowerPivot for easy derivation of .Lat and .Long, and for refreshing the data.

Alternatively SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 or 2012 has similar Map integration, but the end user experience is static.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ee240845.aspx